# Can't connect to internet after installing Ubuntu on my laptop

Tags: ubuntu

After re-installing Ubuntu (12.04) on my laptop (Lenovo), it cannot connect to internet, apparently the network card driver is broken. How can I fix it? Detailed instructions will be really appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Question might fare better on http://askubuntu.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are having issues with the wifi card. 
Try installing [compat-wireless](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable).

Download it on a separate computer, transfer the files to the laptop using a usb, then build it from [source](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable#Unpacking_source)